# Ударение в слове «гуглить»

Tags: орфоэпия, заимствования

*Гугли́ть* или *гу́глить*? *Загугли́ть* или *загу́глить*?
Слово, конечно, жаргонное, но уже весьма и весьма распространённое. В словарях не нахожу. Есть максимально похожие слова: *кругли́ть* и *закругли́ть*, но *обу́глить*.

P. S. Я использую ударение на ***и***, но встречал разные варианты.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Comment: Какое правило регулирует ударение в глаголах на -ить, -иться ("гуглить"­)? -  http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2595120-kakoe-pravilo-reguliruet-udarenie-v-glagolah-na--it--itsja-guglit.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Академический орфографический словарь:
   [**гу́глить**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x), -лю, -лит (*сниж*.)
2. [Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) пишет:

**Вопрос** № 266085
Добрый день!
Сейчас в русский язык постепенно входит неологизм "гуглить", "прогуглить". Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда в этих словах правильно ставить ударение?

**Ответ** справочной службы русского языка
Словарной фиксации нет, но в практике употребления: гУглить, прогУглить, нагУглить.

Answer (score 1):

Пока наука говорит о двояком ударении:

> Ряд глаголов с инфинитивами на -и(-ть) в настоящем (будущем) времени
>   допускает ударение двоякое — на окончании и на корне.

Я произношу "гуглИть", и Грамота.ру мне не указ. Так я чувствую язык.

---

[Какое правило регулирует ударение в глаголах на -ить, -иться ("гуглить"­)?](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2595120-kakoe-pravilo-reguliruet-udarenie-v-glagolah-na--it--itsja-guglit.html)

Просамоцитируюсь слегка:

> Знаю, что такое правило есть, я сама его видела, но оно как-то...
>   улизнуло от меня.
>
> Смотрите: звон - звон**и**ть, ход - ход**и**ть, след - след**и**ть, крен -
>   крен**и**ть(ся), чад - чад**и**ть, сор - сор**и**ть, вред - вред**и**ть, пыль - пыл**и**ть, бас -
>   бас**и**ть, -
>
> так почему же народ упорно хочет гУглить, а не гуглИть, как то делаю
>   я?
>
> В потерянном правиле было что-то о корне из одного слога...
>
> ---

Викисловарь:

[гу́-глить и гу-гли́ть](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)

---

С филологического форума:

[Позиция ударения в слове «гуглить»](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5:%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)

> Я, конечно, понимаю, что личный опыт немного значит, но я крайне редко
>   слышал слово «гу́глить» с ударением на первый слог, практически все
>   ставят ударение на «и» (гугли́ть). И это логично, потому как именно
>   так, как правило, ставится ударение в подобных глаголах. Редкие
>   исключения, конечно, существуют (на ходу можно назвать «спа́мить» и
>   «ба́нить»), но я предлагаю не поддерживать маргинальный вариант и не
>   приводить к тому, чтобы он устоялся и стал ещё одним исключением. В
>   общем, моё предложение — заменить звучащее не по-русски «гу́глить» на
>   корректное «гугли́ть».
>
> ---

С другого форума:

[гуглИть](https://pishu-pravilno.livejournal.com/4001556.html?page=2)

> У отыменных глаголов с суф. -и-, образованных от *односложных*
>   существительных, в абсолютном большинстве случаев ударение смещается
>   на флексии/суффиксы глагола: форс -- форсить, пух -- пушить и т. д.